# ошибка сегментации

Tags: c

Я начал учить си . И тема со строками мне не очень даётся . Вот код :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main ()
{
    char *card="JQK";
    puts(card[0]);

}
```

gcc на linux-е говорит вот что :

```
 expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 extern int puts (const char *__s);
            ^
Ошибка сегментирования
```

Прошу , объясните . А то я что-то не понял .

Answer (score 2):

`puts()` выводит **строку**, а вы пытаетесь вывести отдельный символ. Соответственно, этот символ воспринимается как некоторый адрес, а поскольку это не так - происходит обращение, "куда нельзя".

```
puts(card);
```

выведет вашу строку. Если надо вывести только первый символ - то выводите его так:

```
putchar(card[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `puts` имеет следующее объявление

```
int puts(const char *s);
```

Как видно из объявления, ее единственный параметр имеет тип указателя на строку `const char *`.

Вы же вызываете эту функцию с аргументом, имеющим целочисленный тип `char`.

```
puts(card[0]);
```

В этом случае значение этого выражения `card[0]`, которое равно символу `'J'`, функция рассматривает как адрес и пытается вывести строку, расположенную по этому адресу.

Вы могли бы написать

```
puts( &card[0] );
```

чтобы вывести строку, или

```
putchar( card[0] );
```

чтобы вывести всего лишь один символ.